# Show $\frac{n+1}{2n^2+5} \in \Theta (\frac{1}{n})$ using definition

Tags: calculus, asymptotics, computer-science

Show $\frac{n+1}{2n^2+5} \in \Theta (\frac{1}{n})$ using definition

First showing the upper bound

$\frac{n+1}{2n^2+5} \in O (\frac{1}{n})$

$\frac{n+1}{2n^2+5} \leq \frac{2n}{2n^2} = \frac{1}{n}$

for $n \geq 1$

now showing the lowerbound

$\frac{n+1}{2n^2+5} \in \Omega (\frac{1}{n})$

$\frac{n+1}{2n^2+5} > \frac{n}{2n^2+5} \geq \frac{n}{2n^2 + 5n^2} = \frac{n}{7n^2} = \frac{1}{7n}$

for $n \geq 1$

hence, $\frac{n+1}{2n^2+5} \in \Theta (\frac{1}{n})$

is this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have shown found constant $c_1$ and $c_2$ such that

$$ \frac{c_1}{n}\le\frac{n+1}{2n^2+5} \le \frac{c_2}{n}.$$

You have proven what you want.